# API for stumbleupon - get the number of stumbleupon shares for a page

Tags: php, javascript

Is there an API for getting the number of stumbleupon shares for a page?
I would like to supply a full url of a page and get the number of shares it got on stumbleupon.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: To the best of my (and Google's) knowledge, there is no Stumbleupon API

Comment: @Bulk, There is some kind of API, but it didn't help me. http://www.stumbleupon.com/help/business-tools/supr/supr-api

Comment: I just had a closer look and actually there is an actual API to get information from Stumble, but it doesn't appear (unhelpfully) to include actual stumbles. http://www.stumbleupon.com/help/business-tools/badges/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have an API which will allow you to see the number of shares that a particular page has.  The closest thing we offer is our badge, which will allow you to see the number of likes that one of your pages has.  You can set one up at http://www.stumbleupon.com/dt/badges.